# Springboot Application not starting

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, mapper

I am getting the below error while starting the springboot application. I am attaching the code snippets. I am not able to create the mapper bean.

```
May 28, 2023 2:26:11 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
May 28, 2023 2:26:11 PM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
[main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[main] WARN org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegisterController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restProcessor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'restProcessor': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'placementPortalCatalogue'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'placementPortalCatalogue': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRegisterChain'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegisterChain': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'insertUserRegisterOrder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'insertUserRegisterOrder': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRegisterDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userRegisterDao': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRegisterMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.placement.portal.repository.mapper.UserRegisterMapper' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
[main] INFO org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean - Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
[main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
[main] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
May 28, 2023 2:26:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
[main] INFO org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener - 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRegisterMapper in com.placement.portal.repository.dao.UserRegisterDao required a bean of type 'com.placement.portal.repository.mapper.UserRegisterMapper' that could not be found.
```

The injection point has the following annotations:

```html
package com.placement.portal.service.commands;

import com.placement.portal.common.ChainContext;
import com.placement.portal.common.order.UserRegisterOrder;
import com.placement.portal.repository.dao.UserRegisterDao;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.commons.chain.Context;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class InsertUserRegisterOrder extends CommandWrapper{
    @Autowired
    UserRegisterDao userRegisterDao;

    @Override
    public boolean execute(Context context) throws Exception {
        try {
            ChainContext chainContext = (ChainContext) context;
            UserRegisterOrder userRegisterOrder = chainContext.getUserRegisterOrder();
            userRegisterDao.insertUserRegisterOrder(userRegisterOrder);
            return super.invokeTarget(context);
        }
        finally {

        }
    }
}
```

```html
package com.placement.portal;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class PlacementPortalStudentApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PlacementPortalStudentApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```html
package com.placement.portal.repository.dao;

import com.placement.portal.common.order.UserRegisterOrder;
import com.placement.portal.repository.mapper.UserRegisterMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.sql.SQLException;

@Slf4j
@Repository
public class UserRegisterDao {

    @Autowired
    UserRegisterMapper userRegisterMapper;
    public void insertUserRegisterOrder(UserRegisterOrder userRegisterOrder) throws SQLException {
        if (null == userRegisterOrder){
            log.error("User Register Order is null");
            return;
        }
        userRegisterMapper.insertUserRegisterOrder(userRegisterOrder);

    }
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.5
 

com.amiya
placement-portal-student
1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
Placement-Portal
Placement Portal Student

<java.version>11</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-logging

```
    <!-- Dependency for MySQL Database -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>8.0.33</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>-->


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-chain</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-chain</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis.spring.boot/mybatis-spring-boot-starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.shardingsphere/sharding-jdbc-spring-boot-starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shardingsphere</groupId>
        <artifactId>sharding-jdbc-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```html
package com.placement.portal.repository.mapper;


import com.placement.portal.common.order.UserRegisterOrder;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Insert;
import org.apache.ibatis.annotations.Mapper;

import java.sql.SQLException;

@Mapper
public interface UserRegisterMapper {
    @Insert("insert into user(user_id,request_id) values (#{userId},#{requestId}")
    void insertUserRegisterOrder(UserRegisterOrder userRegisterOrder) throws SQLException;
}
```

Comment: The error message is quite clear: add a UserRegisterMapper bean to your configuration.  Move on to the next error until you've cleaned them all up.

Comment: Could you share  code of `userRegisterMapper`?

Comment: @duffmo How to add bean to configuration?

Comment: error state that bean for mapper class has not created. Use @Component or any suitable stereotype annotation to get that bean scanned.